# Error "exporting" shell functions from within a Java process

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop

I have a script which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function func1() {
  echo "HELLO!"
}
export -f func1

function func2() {
  echo "HI!!"
  func1
}
export -f func2
```

I locally start a hadoop tasktracker and my /usr/lib/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh looks something like this:

```
# .. few configuration params
# source my_shell_file.sh
# my_function
```

When I start the tasktracker everything is fine. It prints out a couple of echo statements that I have inside my_function. When I start a hadoop job with a 'mapper.py' file, it works normally. It even takes the configuration params present in my_function . The problem occurs when I declare my mapper as

```
-mapper 'bash -c "func1 ; python mapper.py"'
```

It then throws this error:

```
/bin/bash: func2: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/bin/bash: error importing function definition for `func2'
/bin/bash: func1: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
/bin/bash: error importing function definition for `func1'
```

I'm not sure what is happening here. I tried 'sh -c' instead of 'bash -c' and I get the same issue.

EDIT: The shell script works fine when I "source" it on the console. It recognizes the functions defined in the shell file on the console.

EDIT2: Added the EXACT contents of the shell file.

Comment: Check that your braces match up. It sounds like the file ends while the parser is still trying to complete the definition of `my_function`.

Comment: Yeah, the braces do match up. Please check the EDIT in my original question.

Comment: Exporting functions is tricky, as it is a `bash` extension. It appears that whatever spawns the mapper is not a `bash` shell, but some other process that doesn't know how to pass the "exported" function to the `bash` instance it spawns. That could account for the error which indicates that the function definition ends prematurely after the first line.

Comment: Yeah, this is executed as part of the mapreduce job that I started, so probably the Java process is spawning this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Hadoop.

Bash functions are passed as regular environment variables so that exporting works across processes:

```
foo='() { echo "hello world"; }' bash -c 'foo'
```

The environment variables generated bash will contain multiple lines, which is normally fine.

Hadoop Streaming, however, has a badly written [Environment class](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-streaming/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/streaming/Environment.java?view=markup) that tries to reimplement `System.getenv()` by naively parsing the output of `env`.

Since it doesn't handle multi-line variables, it destroys your functions.

I tried to submit a bug report, but I didn't have a user for their bug tracker and I didn't want to subscribe to their mailing list. If you'd like this fix, I suggest you submit your own.